# how to open port 53 for bind

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, firewall

how to open port 53 for bind on debian server?

[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] 53 (domain) : Connection refused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Connection refused" generally means that your connection attempt got through to the remote server--in other words, it wasn't blocked by a firewall--but the remote server doesn't have anything listening for connections on that port. If you have command-line access on the remote host, you can use netstat to make sure it actually has something listening on TCP port 53.

Comment: don't forget that it's actually the (ip, port) tuple that matters, not just the port number, unless the IP is `0.0.0.0` (aka `INADDR_ANY`).  In this case, the port is listening, but on the wrong IP address.

Answer (score 13):

"Connection refused" means that BIND isn't actually running on that port, for that particular IP address.

It's a common default configuration for BIND on desktop installs to only listen on the "loopback" IP address.

In fact your `netstat -an` output confirms that - I can see it listening on `127.0.0.1:53` but *not* on `0.0.0.0:53`

Have a look at `/etc/named.conf` and check for the `listen-on` directive.  Mine says:

```
listen-on port 53 { any; };
```

Comment: thx a lot i cant give You reputation because of post is migrated from stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the documentation for your firewall, and whether that firewall is software on the debian server or a hardware device in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help [Debian Open port 81](https://serverfault.com/questions/51354/debian-open-port-81)

53 is going to be a privileged port so you're probably not going to be able to open it without being root or using some other workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

port 53 isnt blocked by iptables